# how to add items into 2dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to get some data and add those into the 2dimensional string array using foreach loop.
I made an integer variable for index reference but it keeps generating this exception error : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

can anyone give some solution for this?
the j.ID needs to be in the first place of every cell which contains three items.

```
string[][] pln_arr = new string[20][];
public int cnt = 0;
foreach (var j in sss)
{
    MessageBox.Show("dddddddd");
    pln_arr[cnt][0] = j.Id;
    MessageBox.Show(pln_arr[0][0]);
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: For the record, that's not a 2D array. A 2D array is a single object where each element is a peer and is declared like `string[,] pln_arr`. What you have is a jagged array, which is a 1D array where each element is a 1D array. It's called a jagged array because of the fact that each inner array can be a different length, where an actual 2D array is always rectangular. You should do some reading on arrays and the difference between multidimensional arrays and jagged arrays. If you actually had a 2D array then you wouldn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the inner array present in `pln_arr`. We can't directly assign value like `pln_arr[cnt][0] = j.Id;`

```
foreach (var j in sss)
{
    MessageBox.Show("dddddddd");
    pln_arr[cnt] = new string[1]; //This was missing. 
                           //^^^^^ Update size of inner array as per your need.
    pln_arr[cnt][0] = j.Id;
    MessageBox.Show(pln_arr[0][0]);
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: could be `new string[1]` aswell - OP didn't define the amount of required "cells"

Comment: I was about to update... Yes we can give array size as we required. I just gave 20 for default.@fubo I updated and gave 1 as size